# How do declare methods that return a Sequence of custom Structs in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

What is the proper way to declare a function that return a Sequence in Swift 4. I tried the following but receive a error stating:

> error: Models.playground:29:13: error: cannot convert return expression of type 'Cars' to return type 'S'
>       return  Cars(cars)
>               ^~~~~~~~~~
>                          as! S

Here is the code I used:

```
import Foundation

struct Car {
    let make:String
    let model:String
}

class Cars: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    typealias Element = Car

    var current = 0
    let cars:[Element]
    init(_ cars:[Element]) {
        self.cars = cars;
    }

    func makeIterator() -> Iterator {
        current = 0
        return self
    }

    func next() -> Element? {
        if current < cars.count {
            defer { current += 1 }
            return cars[current]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

let cars = Cars([Car(make:"Buick", model:"Century"), Car(make:"Buick", model:"LaSabre")])

func getCars<S:Sequence>(cars:[Car]) -> S where S.Iterator.Element == Car {
    return  Cars(cars)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value cannot be a specialization of the `Sequence` protocol.
You can either return `Cars` itself, as [Daniel suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48742332/1187415), or –
if you want to hide the implementation of the sequence – a
“type-erased” sequence:

```
func getCars(cars:[Car]) -> AnySequence<Car> {
    return AnySequence(Cars(cars))
}
```

or even

```
func getCars(cars:[Car]) -> AnySequence<Car> {
    return AnySequence(cars)
}
```

[`AnySequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anysequence) is a
generic struct conforming to the `Sequence` protocol which forwards
to the underlying sequence or iterator from which it was created.
See also [A Little Respect for AnySequence](http://robnapier.net/erasure)
for more examples.

*Remark:* Similarly, it is possible to make `Cars` a `Sequence` 
by returning a type-erased iterator which forwards to the array
iterator:

```
class Cars: Sequence {
    typealias Element = Car

    let cars: [Element]
    init(_ cars: [Element]) {
        self.cars = cars;
    }

    func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<Element> {
        return AnyIterator(cars.makeIterator())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a generic for a specific type. You can either return a `Cars` element (note that `Cars` conforms to `Sequence`, so you are returning a `Sequence` here):

```
func getCars(cars: [Car]) -> Cars {
    return  Cars(cars)
}
```

or use a generic (also a `Sequence`, since it is defined in the generic):

```
func getCars<S: Sequence>(cars: [Car]) -> S {
    return cars as! S
}
```